# Division involving a complex number

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Given this

> $\dfrac{x+1}{x-i}$

What can I do with that?

If i do polynomial division as below, I get:

$$x-i)\overline{x+1} = 1 + \frac{1+i}{x-1}$$

however, I'm not even sure if this is legal maths.
The other thing I think I could to is remove the complex demoninator with the complex conjugate to get:

$$\dfrac{x^2-x(i-1)-i}{x^2+1}$$

but I do not know what to do with this from this point on. I tried polynomial division to get:

$$1- \frac{-x(i-1)-1}{x^2+1}$$

Once again, i'm not sure if this is the correct path.
Some help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to alter the expression? It's already quite short ...

Comment: Try multiplying by $$\frac{x+i}{x+i}$$.

Comment: @MattiP well the book is asking this: "use synthetic division to determine the quotient involving a complex number" and this is the first one of five to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial division (quotient and remainder) in ${\Bbb C}[x]$ gives 
$$x+1 = 1\cdot (x-i) + (1+i).$$

Comment: Thanks @Wuestenfux you're answer has pointed out an error in my maths.